# Problem with TexStudio (Texstudio message error not working )

Tags: texstudio

I have a problem with my Texstudio compiler, as soon as I launch the software the message below appears:

> The procedure entry point CreateDXGIFactory2 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\texstudio\Qt6Gui.dll."

I don't know what to do about this. I have already uninstalled the application, updated it, but my problem still persists.

Comment: Please note that if you're looking for a French speaking community comparable to TeX.SX you can take a look at https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Comment: I have taken the liberty to translate the question into English. Feel free to revert.

Comment: My Question is this :
I have a problem with my Texstudio compiler, as soon as I launch the software the message below appears:

The procedure entry point CreateDXGIFactory2 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\texstudio\Qt6Gui.dll."

I don't know what to do about this. I have already uninstalled the application, updated it, but my problem still persists.